# How to deal with wordpress images?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have blog post featured image that has specific size.

then I want to display it with its excerpt in different page called front-page.php, but I want to display it with larger size.

It already appear in the front page as I want but it is in its normal size.

I just want it to appear larger to be 458 x 355. I already put the dimensions on the code but it is not applied. here is the code

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post['ID'], array(458, 355)); ?>
```

please, what should I do?

Comment: It won't resize images if you pass specific arguments for a specific set of dimensions, it'll just choose the closest pre-sized image. If it did, the site would be incredibly slow as it resized the image on the fly every single time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing explicit dimensions to those APIs won't give you an image with those dimensions unless one already exists. It will choose the image size that's closest.

So, you have 2 options

1. Add a named image size via `add_image_size` that matches the desired dimensions. WordPress will generate an image of this size on upload. You will need to use a regenerate thumbnails type plugin to apply this to past uploads
2. Refactor your CSS to use `object-fit: cover;` then use a larger image size, then specify the width and height of the image explicitly ( which you should be doing anyway instead of relying on the image dimensions to determine the `img` elements width and height. The advantage of this is that images that are smaller, larger images, and images with different aspect ratios, will all work just fine.

e.g.

```css
...yourfeaturedimg... {
    width: 458px;
    height: 355px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

I recommend option 2 as it's more performant, easier to test, and involves following the HTML spec. It also makes your theme more robust and able to handle images better.

Further reading:

- https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_object-fit.asp
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: thanks so much for your helpful reply. but please, could you give me code example  for option 2. and many thanks in advance.

Comment: **I already have**, it's just CSS, target your featured images and add the `object-fit` parameter and set its value to `cover`. No PHP changes should be necessary

Comment: I've added an ultra basic example, but tbh if it's a copy paste solution you want then I can't add that, if not because I have no idea what the HTML markup your featured image has, but because it's such a simple CSS answer that there are thousands of demos and interactive examples for what's literally a 1 liner it would just be silly. At the end of the day, CSS isn't the subject of this stack